# How to "share" a datepicker that needs to call functions in different JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, onselect

I wasn't sure how to question this, as it involves different aspects.

I have a "master" JavaScript file called `timesheet.js`.

And two JavaScript files called `timesheet.timesheet.js` and `timesheet.expenses.js`.

In my `timesheet.js` I have a datepicker that I'd like to use. However, when a date is selected, it needs to call a different function depending on which other JavaScript file I've loaded.

I tried putting the `(#date-picker).datepicker` call in both the `timesheet.js` file and the lower level ones (so I can use `onSelect` as needed), but it seems to override it.

I figure the best approach is to not have the master `timesheet.js` call two separate functions depending on which is called (separation of concerns), but for the two separate ones to know when a date has been selected. How can I achieve this without overriding the functional aspects I added in the master JavaScript file?

Comment: Just a suggestion: you might want to consider renaming this file: `timesheet.timesheet.js`

Comment: Edit: Sorry this is not something I'm able to do.

Comment: @Rail24: `timesheet.timesheet.js` is just bad naming.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Unfortunately I'm stuck with Timesheet -> Timesheet, and Timesheet -> Expenses, and that's the way I've been instructed to implement it.

Comment: Only one of the two will be loaded, correct? Just define different functions for the onSelect handler with the same name in both files, and in `timesheet.js` bind the function with that name to the success event.

Comment: Since I declare `timesheet.js` before the other script, it doesn't seem to be aware of functions in the other script, and I get the error "`sharedFunction` is not defined".

Comment: @Rail24 Just declare them the other way around.

Comment: My two javascript files depend on variables set in the `timesheet.js` namespace.. :(